# scanf is not working in loop of c program

Tags: c

I have created a program to check if a number is even or odd.

But in this  ' scanf("%c",&choice); ' is not working. Could not understand why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    char choice='y';
    for(a=1;choice=='y';a++)
    {
        printf("enter a number to check whether it is even or odd\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a%2==0)
        {
            printf("the no. is even\n");
        }   
        else 
        {
            printf("the no. is odd\n");
        }

        printf("\nto check more y for yes and n for no\n");
        scanf("%c",&choice);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain "is not working".

Comment: Is scanf putting a space into `choice`?  Probably, but since you don't even check the value returned by `scanf` you can't say for sure.

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&choice);` to skip the newline left in the buffer after reading the int.

Comment: Also why use a for loop with extraneous initialization and incrementation when you can just use a while loop?

Comment: Works just fine: `echo 13y14n | ./a.out;`

Comment: Also, `for(a=1;choice=='y';a++)` could just be `while (choice == 'y') {` Or a `do { } while (choice == 'y');`